# ufw is not closing port for incoming packets even after i set the rule?

Tags: networking, security, firewall, ufw

I am trying to stop steam from opening my port 27036.

The problem is that even after i enabled ufw, and even after manually setting a new rule to block this port (even tho by default it should block all incoming packets), the port is still open:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN :

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27036           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6735/steam
```

Note that i already have enabled the ufw and rebooted.

So why is ufw not blocking the port?

Comment: Creating iptables blocking rules either directly or via ufw does not close the port as viewed via netstat. The rules, if they are done correctly, simply prevent any packets from getting to that open port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful for you to post the command you ran to generate the given output, as well as provide the `uwf` command or configuration you created to block the port.

You didn't say which command you ran to generate the output in your question, but I am assuming you're looking at which ports are open by which applications.  Setting up a firewall does not prevent an application from listening on a port.  Instead, setting up a firewall prevents packets from reaching the application if it matches specific conditions.

The best way to test if your firewall is working is to try to access the port on your machine from another machine on your network.  Again, an application can listen to a port and that port be blocked via a firewall, either blocking specific IP addresses/ranges, ports, or other conditions.

`nmap -p 6735 192.168.1.69`

Where **192.168.1.69** is your LAN IP address.

You could block a port access from all IPs, a single IP, a range of IPs, or if you have multiple Network Interface Cards, you could block depending on which NIC the traffic was on.  There are a lot of options.  I say this because depending on your ultimate goal, your `uwf` rule might look different.

Even once you get familiar with creating firewall rules, it is always a good idea to test that they are working as intended, and most often you can't get good results testing from the machine itself and should scan from another machine on the network.

Comment: So is it possible to stop an app from openning the port altogether? I even tried setting an iptable rule but still the port is opened. This is the command i am running: netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN

Comment: You'd tell the application itself which ip and port to listen on.  Not entirely sure why you're going to run the application if you don't want it to open a port.  If you could explain your goal, it might be helpful.

Comment: Just due to security reasons. I understand that ufw will still block packets, but its just a bit annoying to see the port is open and having to check the logs to see if the packets are getting blocked or not. Because i periodically scan open ports, and wanted to see if there's anyway i can stop it from opening altogether.